# Export datatable to excel using LINQ or better way directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I dont want intermittent of using Gridview or Datagrid controls. I want directly to export a DataTable data to an Excel in straight forward.
Is there a way to export by querying the DataTable and export the same into a new Excel.

Please HELP!!

Comment: Can't you just open a connection to Excel Spreadsheet using Connection String (http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) ? Then do whatever you need to do using the connection object ?

Comment: Pretty straightforward (C# only) is to write a csv file and open it in Excel. Careful with date and decimal formats though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this you can do it with XSLT

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/13_Export_dataset_to_Excel_with_XSLT_in_AspNet_20.aspx